# FTDI driver installation problem Linux 64bit

Tags: drivers, compiling

I am trying to install FTDI D2XX drivers from [this](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) site following the instructions on [this](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_220_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_Linux.pdf) page. So I download and extract the 1.4.6 version for linux-64. When I try to use the "make -B" command as described in 3.1 of instructions I get a fatal error :

> make[1](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm): Entering directory
>   '/home/bagjohn/Dropbox/software/libftd2xx-x86_64-1.4.6/release/examples/loopback'
>   cc main.c -o loopback -Wall -Wextra -lftd2xx -lpthread -lrt -Wl,-rpath
>   /usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib main.c:22:10: fatal error: ftd2xx.h:
>   No such file or directory  #include "ftd2xx.h"
>             ^~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. Makefile:9: recipe for target 'loopback' failed

the file "ftd2xx.h" exists in the parent directory and before trying the loopback directory the make has entered and exited other folders with the same command, includind this file, and no error occured.

I've tried this on two different Linux-64 distributions (Debian and Mint) and the error is the same. I didn't find any mention of a corrupt file on the net.

Comment: Why do you need to compile this? I'm using FT232R (serial and bitbanging) and FT2232H (SPI + serial) stuff with FTDI libraries the distribution (Debian) offers. Maybe your distibution has the needed pieces too?

Comment: @yeti I bought this [](https://www.olimex.com/Products/EEG/OpenEEG/EEG-SMT/) piece of hardware (a simple eeg device for home experimentation and in the manual it explicitly states as a prerequisite VCP FTDI drivers. I am not familiar with such stuff. Do I have to download the D2xx or not?

Comment: Linux is not mentioned once in the quickstart guide and the software contains `ElecGuru.exe` which is a `PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows`. So far I cannot see how that should run on Linux. Maybe you can get better infos in Olimex's IRC channel. I think it is: irc://irc.freenode.net/olimex

Comment: The FT232RL [in the EEG's schematics](https://www.olimex.com/Products/EEG/OpenEEG/EEG-SMT/resources/EEG-SMT-SCHEMATIC-REV-B.pdf) looks like mostly a standard USB<—>serial interface to the ATmega16 (plus some isolation). I think, Linux should see this like any other Arduino clone wirh FT232R and a `/dev/ttyUSB<NUMBER>` should appear automagically. The question where the needed software for Linux hides still remains...

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the loopback main.c file.  If you look at all other main.c files in the examples, there is "#include ../../ftd2xx.h".  If you look at the loopback main.c it is "#include ftd2xx.h".  Change the source and you do your "make -B" with no errors.  I've encountered this problem on every different type of system I've installed on.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use a Debian based distro and you have downloaded and decompressed `libftd2xx-x86_64-1.4.6.tgz` correctly.

Follow instructions from `README`.

After, you need to copy the header files:
`ftd2xx.h` and `WinTypes.h` 
to `/usr/local/include` and finally:

```
cd to (YourPath)/libftd2xx-x86_64-1.4.6/release/examples and finally run 
make -B command
```